# How to create digital signature that can not be used to reproduce the message twice

Tags: php, encryption, digital-signature

I am creating a client-server application and I'd like to send data from server to client securely.

Using public/private key algorithms makes sense and in PHP we can use openssl_sign and openssl_verify functions to check that the data came by someone who has the private key.

Now imagine that one of the actions sent by server to client is destructive in nature. If somebody uses an HTTP sniffer to catch this command (which will be signed properly) how can I make sure that the command was executed only when our server sent it and not by a hacker simply reproducing the same command?

OK while writing this I figured out that using auto-increment id to number every sent message could be a simple solution to the problem. Client would just have to check that the incoming message ID is never smaller that the current ID they have stored.

Comment: Don't send the auto-incremented id to the client!  That would defeat the purpose (since the attacker can figure out the next id to send).  Instead, use that in the nonce.  Without the valid id (which both sides should know ahead of time), they'll never be able to figure out a valid nonce.

Comment: I think ID would work as the attacker can not create a valid message without the private key, even if they knew the current ID.

Comment: FYI, the attack you have described is called a *replay attack*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include a nonce (random value, unique for each message) to the message, and on the client keep track of used nonces. I.e. if the attacker takes the signed message and resends it later, the nonce is already used by the client, so the client won't handle the message for the second time.

Comment: and if you get a repeat nonce, ring some alarms. especially if the repeats occur more than once.

Comment: Not bad but a simple auto-increment ID sent with every message could be the solution too. Client would just have to check that the incoming message id is never smaller that the current id they have stored.

Comment: @freediver yes, autoincrementing ID can be an option as well. "Nonce" is a frequently term and entity in cryptography.

Answer (score 3):

*If somebody uses an HTTP sniffer to catch this command (which will be signed properly) how can I further protect the communication to ensure that only commands coming from our server get processed by the client?*

In short, you can't.  If someone can sniff the network traffic, they would be able to get anything that you send.  So unless you pre-share a secret key via an out-of-band mechanism (such as a phone call), you can't reliably do this.  If you pre-share the secret, then all you need to do this:

Server:

```
$message = 'foomessage';
$message .= ':' . hash_hmac('md5', $message, $sharedSecret);
```

Client:

```
list ($message, $hmac) = explode(':', $message, 2);
if ($hmac != hash_hmac('md5', $message, $sharedSecret)) {
    die('invalid signature');
}
```

Note that this is 100% dependent on the shared key.  If someone else got a hold of it, all your signed communication would be tampered with.

Another possible way of detecting a sniffer style attack is to use a syn-ack approach.  Basically, you store a number on the server and on the client.  Each request, you increment both numbers.  You then include that number in a hmac calculation.  Since the client and the server talk to each other, both counts should always be in sync.  But if they are ever off, you know that either some communication failure has taken place, or someone has injected a command (hijacked) with the wrong count.  So while it wouldn't "prevent" a replay attack directly, it would make it MUCH harder since the attacker would need to keep track of every single HTTP request between the server and the client.

But the bottom line is that anyone who's compromised the network to pull off a MITM attack will be able to get around almost anything you can throw at them...  The best ways to secure against it are to pre-share secret keys in an out-of-band manor (such that a HTTP scanner wouldn't be able to detect the shared key).  Then just hmac any message with that pre-shared key.

Comment: The incrementing ID is what I came up with while editing the question. It can be used to prevent replaying the attack, as only the server can send a valid (signed) message and even if the attacker was able to track the current count, they cant create a new valid message.

Comment: How will this prevent replaying (i.e. sending the same message twice)?

Comment: @Eugene: Well, if you replay, the count that was hashed into the message will now be wrong (since the original one was incremented).  So the client or server should be able to detect it (since the hash with the current count will be wrong).  Now it won't prevent a good MITM attack.  But it will detect one on the next valid request as well.  So if you detect bad counts, kill the entire session and require a re-authentication.  That won't stop the MITM attack between requests.  But it will detect it eventually...

Comment: @ircmaxell yes, all of this is correct, I just pointed that in the initial variant of question the OP asked about preventing replaying. The counter appeared later.

Comment: What's a MITM attack? Any links?

Comment: @Freediver MITM is [Man In The Middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need an interpretation of the "One-Time Pad Cipher" in PHP?

**One Time Pad**
The one-time pad is a long sequence of random letters. These letters are combined with the plaintext message to produce the ciphertext. To decipher the message, a person must have a copy of the one-time pad to reverse the process. A one-time pad should be used only once (hence the name) and then destroyed. This is the first and only encryption algorithm that has been proven to be unbreakable.

To encipher a message, you take the first letter in the plaintext message and add it to the first random letter from the one-time pad. For example, suppose you are enciphering the letter S (the 19th letter of the alphabet) and the one-time pad gives you C (3rd letter of the alphabet). You add the two letters and subtract 1. When you add S and C and subtract 1, you get 21 which is U. Each letter is enciphered in this method, with the alphabet wrapping around to the begining if the addition results in a number beyond 26 (Z).

To decipher a message, you take the first letter of the ciphertext and subtract the first random letter from the one-time pad. If the number is negative you wrap around to the end of the alphabet.

Comment: Can you please provide an explanation in context of the question?

Answer (score 0):

Make an hash (md5) out of each message and add the microtime timestamp to it.